# How to recover data on replaced RAID 1 virtual drive, PERC 710 controller

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, data-recovery

Today I created a new RAID 0 virtual drive using the RAID setup wizard of my lifecycle controller for my two new 4TB SAS dell hardrives.

Unfortunately, I misread the warning saying that creating this virtual drive would delete all other virtual drives.

Therefore my 2x512GB RAID 1 that came with the T320 poweredge server got deleted. I realise now I should have used the advanced BIOS configuration utility to add a new drive instead of the wizard, unfortunately it's too late.

The data erased is not critical, but would be very handy to have, I since then build another RAID 1 drive with those disks using the default settings, but have not initialized it.

I was wandering if I could try to recover the data with a recovering tool. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score -1):

The recovery of data is possible if you didn't put any data on new created RAID 0. Otherwise part of the data or whole data can be overwritten. Previous RAID 1 configuration was mirror and you can attach one of the drives to another computer and run data recovery scavenge utility. There are several of them.

Comment: Greetings, actually I just reinstalled windows 10 and it automatically detected the deleted partition, I was able to recover all data.